# My strange friend

Tags: logical-deduction

One day I was out taking a walk during my lunch and a good friend of mine ran up to me suddenly and shouted "nine!" at me and then pointed at his watch and ran off. Obligingly I looked at the time and saw that it was twenty-six minutes before one and I immediately understood.

What day did this is odd event happen?

Comment: One odd thing about the usage of this tag.... [Deductive vs Inductive reasoning](http://www.livescience.com/21569-deduction-vs-induction.html)

Comment: @Khale_Kitha The answer can be deduced from the information given. I  may  need to add more information if answers are too far off.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This happened

> 06/07/08 (June 7, 2008 or July 6, 2008, depending on where you're from)

because

> 26 minutes before one is 12:34, and I'm guessing it was precisely 5 seconds past the turn of the minute, making it 12:34:05 on 06/07/08, and the "Nine!" would be next in this sequence.

Comment: For whatever reason I had forgotten about seconds. And although this is not the actual date I was looking for I'll give you credit as it accounts for something I had forgotten to include.

Comment: @dcfyj Are you going to give us the original answer?

Comment: @Simple Art My bad. The answer I originally is the one ruudvan posted. I chose this one rather than the one I expected for the reason I wrote in my original comment.

Comment: I still do not get it, please explain how the day has been calculated?

Comment: ok I got it now, but still cannot get the logic behind the shout of the friend

Comment: @albanx look at the individual numbers ignoring the zeros.

Answer (score 20):

This happened on

> 5/6/78 - June 5th '78 or May 6th '78 depending on which country they are in. The location isn't specified. Same reason as @Matt - The friend wanted to complete the sequence - 12:34 5/6/78 ... 9 !

Comment: Like this more than the answer